# If condition in ARM Template

Tags: azure-rm-template

Is it possible to set a value based on parameter value?

Let's say I have a reource in my arm template as follows:

```
parameters:

env
param1
param2

resources:

{
  "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
  "apiVersion": "2018-05-01",
  "url": <value-based-on-if-condition>
}
```

If parameter('env') = "a", set url value = parameter('param1').

If parameter('env') = "b", set url value = parameter('param2')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use if function in the ARM Template like:

```
if(condition, trueValue, falseValue)
```

Please refer this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/template-functions-logical#if) for explanation and examples.